# Add a bookmark to a pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#

I'm trying to merge pdfs and add bookmarks to them, I found a way to add a bookmark, by chapter, but the chapter aperse on the page, is there a way to add only the bookmark, or to make the chapter not visible.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The chapter or chapter number?

If it's the chapter number, change the chapter.numberDepth = 0.
If it's the chapter title, change the chapter.Title = " ";

But leave chapter.BookMark.Title = "Whatever I want";